# Pick account from text file perform action and then pick another and perform a different action

Tags: c#

I have a text file with accounts like so:

```
username|password
another|differntpassword
andanther|password123
```

I am using syndication to get articles from an rss feed, now my problem is, inside the syndication foreach I am using another foreach to select an account, but because my account foreach is inside the syndication foreach, it will perform the same action for all accounts, then the next syndication item it will do the same, rather than a different syndication item for a differnt account...

My code:

```
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{

}
```

As you can see with my code, it will post the same syndication item for all accounts, so how can I move on from the account foreach once that one has completed, but on the next syndication item use the next account (by line)

I am trying to complete 1 action per account and then once I have no more accounts, start from the beggining of the accounts

For example, say I have 10 syndication items and 5 accounts:

**Syndication items:**

```
test
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9
test10
```

And say I have only 5 accounts

```
account1
account2
account3
account4
account5
```

I want to post each syndication with a differnt account until I have no more account and then start from the start of the account file like so

```
test | account1
test2 | account 2
test3 | account 3
test4 | account 4
test5 | account 5
test6 | account 1 // because we have no more accounts, start from the begginng 
test7 | account 2
test8 | account 3
test9 | account 4
test10 | account 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload which provides item index to projection delegate:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(accounts);
var pairs = feed.Items.Select((item, i) => new { item, line = lines[i % lines.Length] });

foreach(var pair in pairs)
   // use pair.item and pair.line
```

I also use here [modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) operator to get the remainder after dividing syndication item index by count of accounts (lines). That gives index in lines array that should be used for current syndication item.

Comment: Ooops, updated op. 'cause I'm trying to do 1 post per account, then once completed then start over with the accounts

Comment: @dontmindmeyo can you clarify what that means? As I understand from question you want to perform each syndication item for first account, then go to second account and perform each syndication item for second account, etc

Comment: Sorry. I mean I want to do the syndication item foreach like so, but for each item in the syndication I want to use a differnt account, until I reach the end of my textfile (with the accounts) and then start from the top again. Sorry if it doesnt make sense.

Comment: Legend. Thank you.